# How to stop Visual Studio 2022 from appending Debug\ to the output path?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I recently upgraded from VS Express 2017 to VS 2022 Pro.

When I added a new project to an old solution I found that VS keeps adding Debug\ to the project's output base path.

I already managed to get rid of the target framework by adding

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to the project file manually as recommendet on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2022

But I can't figure out how to get rid of Debug\

So instead of `bin\Debug\Plugins\` I keep getting the dlls put into `bin\Debug\Plugins\Debug\`

How can I restrict Visual Studio's output to the base output path?

Comment: What's the value of the `OutputPath` property? Is it specified in your project file?

Comment: `<BaseOutputPath>..\bin\Debug\Plugins\</BaseOutputPath>` @PMF

Comment: No, `OutputPath`, the IDE no longer allows setting it for SDK-style projects so it has to be done in the project file.  There is also `OutputDir`.  The msbuild comment is a bit hard to interpret, I'll quote it: "For Legacy projects using only Common targets, this property (i.e. OutputPath) is usually specified in the project file and is used to initialize OutDir. Some SDKs including the .NET SDK derive this automatically.  OutDir and OutputPath are distinguished for legacy reasons, and OutDir should be used if at all possible."  Not fighting the machine is recommended.

Comment: @HansPassant There was no OutputPath property. When I set it it works fine. Is there no way to add these options via Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Changing `BaseOutputPath` to `OuputPath` helped solving this problem in my case.